# PHP updating value in table from array

Tags: php

I am trying to update a value in a table I get from an array.  I'm not getting any errors but it is not updating my table ex_test_setting.  What am I doing wrong?  I followed other posts and googled it but I cant get a correct answer.

```
echo "<strong>Checking if the test points changed</strong>";
echo "</BR>";
$getTotalPoints = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(points_available) FROM ex_question WHERE test_name = '$tid_mod1'") or die(mysql_error()); 
$totalPoints = mysql_fetch_array($getTotalPoints);
echo "New points for test: " . $totalPoints['SUM(points_available)'];
echo "</BR>";

$sql2="SELECT DISTINCT point FROM ex_test_setting WHERE testid = '$tid_mod1'";
$res2=mysql_query($sql2);
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($res2)) {
$point1=$row2['point'];
echo "Old points for test: " . $point1;
echo "</BR>";
}


if ($totalPoints['SUM(points_available)'] <> $point1) {
echo "Updating...";
$newpoint = $totalPoints['SUM(points_available)'];
echo $newpoint;
mysql_query("UPDATE ex_test_setting SET point = '$newpoint' WHERE test_name = '$tid_mod1'");
}
```

Comment: Did you get any value when you run the line `echo $newpoint;` ? Also what's the structure of `ex_test_setting` table ? .. Finally its better to write `SELECT SUM(points_available) AS sum1` so you can get the value as `$totalPoints['sum1']`

Comment: @ladiesMan217 , it's commonly used in PHP , it's like `!=`

Comment: suppose to be not equal to, thank you, did not pick it up, it should be !=

Comment: @Ashraf I get the correct value when I echo $newpoint, but it is not updating the table.  Also tried the AS sum1 option (also in answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code :-

```
echo "<strong>Checking if the test points changed</strong>";
echo "</BR>";
$getTotalPoints = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(points_available) as point_av FROM ex_question WHERE test_name = '$tid_mod1'") or die(mysql_error()); 
$totalPoints = mysql_fetch_array($getTotalPoints);
echo "New points for test: " . $totalPoints['point_av'];
echo "</BR>";

$sql2="SELECT DISTINCT point FROM ex_test_setting WHERE testid = '$tid_mod1'";
$res2=mysql_query($sql2);
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($res2)) {
$point1=$row2['point'];
echo "Old points for test: " . $point1;
echo "</BR>";
}


if ($totalPoints['point_av'] != $point1) {
echo "Updating...";
$newpoint = $totalPoints['point_av'];
echo $newpoint;
mysql_query("UPDATE ex_test_setting SET point = '$newpoint' WHERE test_name = '$tid_mod1'");
}
```

Comment: You should explain what you changed and why, its about lurning too ^^

Comment: @sam_13 tried it and went through all the code again but it is not updating.  Also checked that ex_test_setting field is int.

Comment: I think there was something wrong with my update query because I deleted and typed it again and now it is working